# Strange/buggy behavior when selecting Function as action for a Logic App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

This guy showed the behaviour in a GIF so I'm not going to repeat with screenshots.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33927.azure-logic-apps-dynamic-hello-world-using-azure-functions-inside-logic-apps.aspx

Two issues. First the "Create New Function" option is initially missing.

Second, when you click an existing function, the name gets appended with "loading" and then after a moment the panel is replaced with only "Create New Function".

There was no satisfactory response to that thread and I'm having exactly the same issue. Therefore I am posting it here.

Seems very broken/buggy to me too.

Answer (score 0):

The post you linked to I only see an article with a few comments but none addressing this bug? Either way here's a few updates:

- The create new function only shows up after selecting a valid function app. This is currently by design as the Function API requires an app to create new. In future we may add experience to create an app and a function, but for now should link to article on how to create an app/container.
- There was a bug reported early this week on the create function experience that resulted in failure to create a function from designer. We worked with functions team and found the fix. It should be shipping out shortly. I'm not sure from this post if that's the bug you hit but may be related.

Let me know if that helps or if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Also after re-sending question, you will only see functions listed in the designer that are JSON webhook functions (the Generic Webhook template is this). If you have an HTTP trigger for function and setting is set to Generic JSON it should show up in this list.

Comment: One issue is that the documentation is wrong. For example in this page (first to come up when I google)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33927.azure-logic-apps-dynamic-hello-world-using-azure-functions-inside-logic-apps.aspx

shows "Create New Function" in the screenshot under 

From the search box select “Show Azure Functions in my subscription” and then “Create New Function”.

Comment: And it would be nice if you could choose which language when you create a function within Logic Apps.

Comment: And this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-azure-functions

Doesn't have a screenshot of the "Create New Function" operation. I think that for completeness one should be added. And the incorrect screenshot I referenced previously should be fixed.